# Server(GUI) freezes after starting. Works fine in Console

Tags: c#, multithreading, server, client

[Server(GUI).png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGL7c.png)

**Server ( GUI )**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Server_ProfiChat
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        static readonly object _lock = new object();
        static readonly Dictionary<int, TcpClient> list_clients = new Dictionary<int, TcpClient>();


        public static void handle_clients(object o)
        {
            int id = (int)o;
            TcpClient client;

            lock (_lock) client = list_clients[id];

            while (true)
            {
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int byte_count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                if (byte_count == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, byte_count);
                broadcast(data);
                Console.WriteLine(data);
                //var chatline = txtChat.Text;
                Form1 formObj = new Form1();
                formObj.txtChat.Text += data;
            }

            lock (_lock) list_clients.Remove(id);
            client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();
        }

        public static void broadcast(string data)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data + Environment.NewLine);

            lock (_lock)
            {
                foreach (TcpClient c in list_clients.Values)
                {
                    NetworkStream stream = c.GetStream();

                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }
        }








        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int count = 1;

            string serverIP = txtServerIP.Text;
            int serverPort = Int32.Parse(txtServerPort.Text);

            TcpListener ServerSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(serverIP), serverPort);
            ServerSocket.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = ServerSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                lock (_lock) list_clients.Add(count, client);
                Console.WriteLine("Someone connected!!");

                Thread t = new Thread(handle_clients);
                t.Start(count);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Server ( Console )

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace testServ
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly object _lock = new object();
        static readonly Dictionary<int, TcpClient> list_clients = new Dictionary<int, TcpClient>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count = 1;

            TcpListener ServerSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.169"), 123);
            ServerSocket.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = ServerSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                lock (_lock) list_clients.Add(count, client);
                Console.WriteLine("Someone connected!!");

                Thread t = new Thread(handle_clients);
                t.Start(count);
                count++;
            }
        }

        public static void handle_clients(object o)
        {
            int id = (int)o;
            TcpClient client;

            lock (_lock) client = list_clients[id];

            while (true)
            {
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int byte_count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                if (byte_count == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, byte_count);
                broadcast(data);
                Console.WriteLine(data);
            }

            lock (_lock) list_clients.Remove(id);
            client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();
        }

        public static void broadcast(string data)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data + Environment.NewLine);

            lock (_lock)
            {
                foreach (TcpClient c in list_clients.Values)
                {
                    NetworkStream stream = c.GetStream();

                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client (console)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace test_Clie
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.166");
            int port = 123;
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(ip, port);
            Console.WriteLine("client connected!!");
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
            Thread thread = new Thread(o => ReceiveData((TcpClient)o));

            thread.Start(client);

            string s;
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((s = Console.ReadLine())))
            {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
                ns.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
            thread.Join();
            ns.Close();
            client.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("disconnect from server!!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void ReceiveData(TcpClient client)
        {
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
            byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[1024];
            int byte_count;

            while ((byte_count = ns.Read(receivedBytes, 0, receivedBytes.Length)) > 0)
            {
                Console.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes, 0, byte_count));
                Console.Write(ns);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Im a beginner but to me it seems to have to do with the threading?
Also because it freezes I cant see if the rest is working, any ideas on how to improve workflow, as in searching for the exact point the mistakes are? Im wasting alot of time searching anything because I dont know how to properly test, debug and pinpoint the mistakes I made.

Appreciate any help =))

Comment: How long does it take in console to run?  The form will be locked for same amount of time.  To prevent locking in a Form Application you have to run code in a BackGroundWorker. (or async task).

Comment: Im a beginner but to me it seems to have to do with the threading? Answer: Yes. Especially you are using UI Thread. It is waiting for a connection.

Comment: Rather than `lock/Dictionary`, use `ConcurrentDictionary`, which does what you are trying to do, but better.

Answer (score 0):

Streams generally do exactly what you ask of them.   If you ask for 10 bytes, then a `Read` will not return until there are 10 bytes to return.  What `stream.Read` will not do, is return fewer bytes just because that is how many have been received.

This code will block until 1024 bytes have been read.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int byte_count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
if (byte_count == 0)
{
     break;
}
```

Is that what you are expecting?

Generally, byte based protocols have a header, which contains how many bytes are in the payload.

Imagine the protocol below:

`<stx><soh><len><eoh><payload><etx>`

- stx = Start of transmission
- soh = Start of header
- len = length of payload
- eoh = End of header
- etx = End of transmission

To read a complete packet you MUST read 4 bytes, and then you MUST read enough bytes to complete the payload, then the last byte should be ETX.

```
byte[5] header;
stream.Read(buffer, 0, 4);

int payloadLength = header[2];
byte[] payload = new byte[payloadLength];
stream.Read(payload, 0, payloadLength);
stream.Read() == ETX;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient) method is blocking. You could try using its asynchronous counterpart instead, combined with [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/):

```
private async void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* ... */
    TcpClient client = await ServerSocket.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
    /* ... */
}
```